# Return a list of Directory (Folder) names that match a partial string

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, directory

I need someone to point me in the right direction.

**Goal:**
Return a list of **Folder Names** in a path that contain a string in their name. For example: The Path has a Directory named Pictures_New and Videos_New. The string I am searching with is "Pictures_" and "Videos_".

It all works with one string parameter being passed as a search string. My problem is getting it to work with multiple filters. I know it is easily done with file names and extensions.

This is being passed to `GetFolders()`:

```
string[] filterStrings = { "Pictures_", "Videos_" }
```

**Rest of my code:**

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFolders(string path, string[] filterStrings, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    IEnumerable<string> folders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "Pictures_*.*", searchOption);
    var resultFolders = new List<string>();

    if(filterStrings.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var foldername in folders)
        {
            string folderName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(foldername));

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderName) || Array.IndexOf(filterStrings, "*" + folderName) < 0)
            {
                // This leaves us only with the Directory names. No paths.
                var b = (foldername.Substring(foldername.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
                resultFolders.Add(b);
            }
        }
    }
    return resultFolders;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `"Pictures_*.*"` would match any directory, it looks more like a file filter...

Comment: But it does, unless I am totally missing the point. There are currently no files in those directories. And I get all Directories with Pictures_ in the name returned.

Comment: Why not use filterStrings.Contains(folderName) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linq `SelectMany` to parse your list of filters and return a list of the results with `Directory.GetDirectories();`
It will of course return all the Sub Directories that match the filter. Use just "*".

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetFolders(string path, string[] filterStrings, SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    List<string> resultFolders = filterStrings
                 .SelectMany(flt => Directory.GetDirectories(path, flt, searchOption))
                 .ToList();
    return resultFolders;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var patterns = new[] { "Pictures_*", "Videos_*" };
var dirsFound = new List<string>();
foreach (var dir in patterns.Select(pattern => Directory.GetDirectories(@"my path", pattern).ToArray()))
{
    dirsFound.AddRange(dir);
}
```

Comment: A slightly optimized version would be to use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` and `AddRange`. `var dirsFound = patterns.SelectMany(pattern => Directory.GetDirectories(@"my path", pattern).ToArray())`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not looping through each of your filter strings:

```
var folders = new List<string>();
foreach (var filterString in filterStrings)
{
    folders.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, filterString, searchOption););
}
```